# Encontrar palavra em arquivo txt em python

Tags: python

Tenho um programa chamado `anagrams.py` e a função dele é mostrar as permutações de uma palavra digitada pelo usuário caso a mesma esteja no arquivo `words.txt`.

Este é o código completo:

```py
""" Anagrams by WhoisBsa """
from itertools import permutations
import sys


def findPermutation(wrd):
    """ Find the permutation of the words """
    parmutationList = permutations(wrd)
    for item in parmutationList:
        print(''.join(item))


def checkWord(wrd, wordLine):
    """ Checks whether the word exists in the file or not """
    while True:
        for i in wordLine.readlines():
            if wrd in i:
                result = True
                break
            else:   
                result = False
        if result:
            findPermutation(wrd)
            break
        else:
            print('This word is not available')
            break


def main():
    """ Main function """
    with open('words.txt', 'r') as f:
        word = sys.argv[1].upper()
        checkWord(word, f)
        f.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Esse código roda perfeitamente com uma exceção: na verificação da função `checkWord` a condição

```py
if wrd in i:
```

procura qualquer palavra que satisfaça a condição, ou seja, se eu digito a palavra `house` e rodo o código, a intenção é que o retorno (caso esteja no arquivo) seja todas as permutações da palavra house, entretanto, no arquivo há a palavra `blockhouse`, e com isso o programa verifica se há house no arquivo e quando ele encontra a palavra blockhouse ele para e faz as permutações da palavra house.

Eu sei que a condição `if wrd in i` vai validar **qualquer** palavra que satisfaça a condição. A questão é que se eu uso

```py
if wrd == i:
```

o programa não funciona, ele vai direto pro `else`.

Um outro problema é que se eu digitar *hou* o programa vai encontrar *blockhouse* e fazer o anagrama da palavra *hou* sendo que a mesma não existe.

Pensei usar o método `regex` para válidar isso mas eu não sei como aplicar nesse código.

Comment: Esta um pouco confuso o que vc quer, veja que house não é anagrama (e nem permutacao) de blockhouse e nem vice-versa. Se o usuario digita House e no arquivo tem Blockhouse e nao tem house, então a palavra nao está no arquivo, a não ser que vc queira procurar substrings dentro das strings no arquivo (ou talvez os dois: anagramas e substrings), ai o enunciado (e o codigo)  seriam outros.

Comment: @Sidon esse é o problema, no arquivo nao tem house mas tem blockhouse, eu quero que retorne que nao há house no arquivo mas isso nao acontece, e vê que existe a palavra blockhouse e entao faz a permutacao da palavra house pois no codigo a permutationList recebe as permutacoes da variável word:  `permutationList = permutations(wrd)`

Comment: Vamos ver se entendi: Se  o usuario digitar house, vce tem que procurar por house e todos os anagramas de house no arquivo, é Isso?

Comment: Dica que não tem a ver com a pergunga: você não precisa (nem deve, mas só por questão legibilidade) chamar o `.close` de um arquivo se usou o `with` para abri-lo. O `with` já fecha o arquivo.

Comment: @Sidon se eu digitar house eu vou procurar por house e se existir house no arquivo eu faço os anagramas da palavra house :)

Comment: @jsbueno valeu pela dica! :)

Comment: Ok, veja se minha resposta ajuda.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uma solução, tal como indicou na sua pergunta, passa pelo uso de expressões regulares. Fica aqui uma exemplo, alterando apenas a sua função `checkWord`:

```
def checkWord(wrd, wordLine):
    """ Checks whether the word exists in the file or not """
    for line in wordLine:
        if re.search(r'\b' + re.escape(wrd) + r'\b', line, flags=re.IGNORECASE):
            findPermutation(wrd)
            return

    print('This word is not available')
```

Apenas quando a palavra **exacta** for encontrada, e não uma palavra derivada (por por meio do acréscimo de um sufixo ou prefixo), as permutações serão geradas.

Dependendo do tamanho do ficheiro, pode ser mais eficiente ler o seu conteúdo de uma vez e efectuar apenas uma pesquisa.

```
def checkWord(wrd, wordLine):
    """ Checks whether the word exists in the file or not """
    if re.search(r'\b' + re.escape(wrd) + r'\b', wordLine.read(), flags=re.IGNORECASE):
        findPermutation(wrd)
    else:   
        print('This word is not available')
```

Não se esqueça de importar o módulo `re`

O `\b` é uma espécie de âncora. Quando adicionado a um dos lados da regex vai capturar o padrão especificado no início, fim ou a palavra exata. Neste caso, pretendemos a palavra exacta, pelo que adicionamos o `\b` no início e fim da palavra a pesquisar.

[Da wikipédia](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Express%C3%A3o_regular):

> \b    Casa a separação de palavras, o que inclui também o começo (^) e o
>   fim ($) da cadeia de caracteres testada. A definição dos caracteres
>   que formam palavras varia de acordo com a implementação, mas é seguro
>   assumir pelo menos [a-zA-Z0-9_]. Havendo suporte, o atalho \w é uma
>   alternativa válida. O Java é uma notável exceção na medida em que
>   suporta \b mas não \w. Notar que apesar de parecida com os limites de
>   palavras definidos pela POSIX, esta sequência de escape não distingue
>   o começo e o final da palavra, somente a separação em si.

Comment: Por questões de velocidade, escolhi a solução do @bruno por ser mais rápida. Obrigado a todos que colaboraram! :)

Answer (score 2):

O operador `in` do Python tem comportamentos diferentes se o segundo operando (o que vem depois do `in`) for uma `str` ou `bytes`, e se for um outro tipo de sequência.

No caso de você fazer `a in b` e ambos serem strings, se `a` existir em qualquer posição dentro de `b`, ele retorna `True` - mesmo que  "a" tenha mais de um item de comprimento. assim `"house" in "housekeeper"` é `True`. Se, no entanto, `b` for outro tipo de sequência, como uma lista, somente se uma cópia de `a` estiver na sequência o resultado é True: 
`"house" in ["housekeeper",]` - retorna `False`: aqui  "housekeeper" é um elemento dentro da lista que está sendo "investigada" pelo `in`.

Portanto, você resolve seu problema facilmente se, ao invés de fazer as buscas direto dentro do texto lido de cada linha do arquivo, você converter cada linha para uma lista de palavras inteiras antes.

Você não dá exemplo do seu arquivo .txt, mas supondo-se que ele não tenha pontuação além de espaços em branco e quebras de linha, é só trocar a linha

```
for i in wordLine.readlines():
     if wrd in i:
         ...
```

Por:

```
 for line in wordline: 

      words = line.strip().split()
      if wrd in words:
          ...
```

Coementando as mudanças:

- eu processo a linha, removendo espaços em branco de newline do final
  da linha chamando o `.strip()`. (Nesse ponto, se houver pontuação, você poderia remove-la, aí sim usando expressões regulares para remover os assentos)
- eu divido a linha em uma lista de palavras onde houver espaços em branco, com o método "split". Uma linha com "housekeeper heart mother" fica `['hosekepper', 'heart', 'mother']`

E, sem ser essencial para o problema:

- eu removo a chamada ao método `readlines`: Python não precisa do readlines para iterar as linhas de um arquivo num `for` - esse método praticamente existe por razões históricas
- Não uso a variável `i` para a variável do `for`: `i` é muito usado na maioria das outras linguagens que não tem um "for each" prático, que percorre a sequência desejada diretamente - nessas linguagens é comum ter uma variável "i" que vai servir de "índice"  e ser descartada logo em seguida. o `for` de Python já obtemos direto o elemento que interessa (nesse caso, as linhas do arquivo), então é melhor dar um nome que faça sentido pra variável.

Além disso tem outros pontos do seu programa que precisam de atenção: você tem um `while True` que não é usado pra nada, por exemplo (dentro dele tem um `if` que tem um break no `if` e no `else`) - mas não tem  a ver com a sua pergunta.

Comment: Bela resposta @jsbueno. +1

Indiquei a alternativa com a expressão regular porque pensava que era um arquivo de texto "normal", em que as palavras podem ter pontuação imediatamente antes ou depois.

Comment: @bruno a resposta do @jsbueno foi ótima, mas no meu ver, a sua foi um pouco mais ligeira, e como eu estou estudando o modulo `re`, resolvi aderir a sua solução. Mesmo assim, muito obrigado @jsbueno! :)

Answer (score 0):

De acordo com os comentários, o que vc precisa fazer é apenas procurar a palavra digitada no texto e, se existir, criar os anagramas, para isso criei um exemplo simulando a leitura de um texto em um arquivo:

```
import io
from itertools import permutations

txt = '''
Este texto contem house e uma anagrama esouh também casa menino
boy asac boi e mala mas pode-se ver sam e homeoffice assim como
boi e mala etc.
'''

text = io.StringIO(txt).read().split()

palavra = input ('digite a palavra:')

permutacoes = None
if palavra in text:
    permutacoes = permutations(palavra)

if permutacoes is not None:
    anagramas = []
    for item in permutacoes:
      anagramas.append(''.join(item)) 
    print(anagramas)      
else:
    print('Não encontrado')
```

Saida (considerando q o usuario tenha digitado 'house'):

```
['house', 'houes', 'hosue', 'hoseu', 'hoeus', 'hoesu', 'huose', 'huoes', 
'husoe', 'huseo', 'hueos', 'hueso', 'hsoue', 'hsoeu', 'hsuoe', 'hsueo', 'hseou',
 'hseuo', 'heous', 'heosu', 'heuos', 'heuso', 'hesou', 'hesuo', 'ohuse', 'ohues', 
'ohsue', 'ohseu', 'oheus', 'ohesu', 'ouhse', 'ouhes', 'oushe', 'ouseh', 'ouehs',
 'ouesh', 'oshue', 'osheu', 'osuhe', 'osueh', 'osehu', 'oseuh', 'oehus', 'oehsu',
 'oeuhs', 'oeush', 'oeshu', 'oesuh', 'uhose', 'uhoes', 'uhsoe', 'uhseo', 'uheos',
 'uheso', 'uohse', 'uohes', 'uoshe', 'uoseh', 'uoehs', 'uoesh', 'ushoe', 'usheo',
 'usohe', 'usoeh', 'useho', 'useoh', 'uehos', 'uehso', 'ueohs', 'ueosh', 'uesho',
 'uesoh', 'shoue', 'shoeu', 'shuoe', 'shueo', 'sheou', 'sheuo', 'sohue', 'soheu',
 'souhe', 'soueh', 'soehu', 'soeuh', 'suhoe', 'suheo', 'suohe', 'suoeh', 'sueho',
 'sueoh', 'sehou', 'sehuo', 'seohu', 'seouh', 'seuho', 'seuoh', 'ehous', 'ehosu',
 'ehuos', 'ehuso', 'ehsou', 'ehsuo', 'eohus', 'eohsu', 'eouhs', 'eoush', 'eoshu',
 'eosuh', 'euhos', 'euhso', 'euohs', 'euosh', 'eusho', 'eusoh', 'eshou', 'eshuo',
 'esohu', 'esouh', 'esuho', 'esuoh']
```

**Obs.:**
Claro que dependendo do conteudo do seu arquivo vc precisa fazer um trabalho de "sanitização" pontuação tb tera que ser sanitizada.

[Veja funcionando no repl.it](https://repl.it/@sidonduarte/anagram-python)